# A PHP check to see if the mail server is working?

Tags: php, email

is there a way to check if the email server is working via PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Which mail server? Outgoing? Incoming? In what kind of environment? If it's outgoing, what method would you use to send mail - `mail()` or a mailer class? What platform - Linux/Unix or Windows? What would "working" exactly entail - that it's running, or that it is in fact able to send out E-Mail? I find it pretty cheeky to downvote people's answers with this hazy a question. (*if* that was you downvoting sAc.)

Comment: *(reference)* http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/docs and in particular `Net_SMTP::connect  ( int $timeout  = null  )` and in case you want IMAP or POP, there is classes for that in PEAR too - or in Zend Framework. Apart from this I agree with Pekka.

Comment: Linux using mail(), outgoing.

Comment: That still isn't clear. Do you want to know if the receiving mail server is up or do you want to know if mail() is actually able to use the underlying mail program, e.g sendmail (see http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php) - that's a fundamental difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the only really, really reliable way of testing whether the mail server works is to actually send an E-Mail.

- Use `mail()` to send out an E-Mail to an external address (i.e. one that is not hosted on the local server) containing a unique identifier in the subject. The external mailbox belongs to you and must have spam filtering turned off
- Have a PHP script poll the recipient mail box for new messages, e.g. using one of the libraries Gordon provides in the comments
- Depending on server, it could take 5-10 minutes' time because of possible delayed delivery (Greylisting)
- Once the E-Mail has successfully arrived, report success
- If the E-Mail hasn't arrived within the time frame specified by you, report failure

if you have a sender/recipient server relationship that you know to deliver E-Mails instantly, you might get around the "wait for 5-10 minutes" part and just `sleep()` 10-20 seconds before checking the mail box. Otherwise, you may have to set up a cron job if you can't run a PHP script for that long, which complicates things.

That said, a much simpler but much more basic test for whether the mail server works is sending the test E-Mail using `mail()`, and checking its return value. If it returns `false`, there is something fundamentally wrong with your mail setup. There are many, many eventualities that will *not* return `false` here though, so it's not really a thorough check.